# Add as many text fields as I want and send it to mongodb

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, mongodb

Under normal circumstances, I can write the data in the 2 text fields that I created at the beginning and send it to the db, but when I add a button next to the throw to Mongodb button (the button's function is to add a new text field every time it is clicked), I cannot take the data from the new text fields there and assign Mongodb, can you help?

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.3.7/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<style>
    .democlass {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        height: 34px;
        padding: 6px 12px;
        font-size: 14px;
        line-height: 1.42857143;
        color: #555;
        background-color: #fff;
        background-image: none;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        border-radius: 4px;
        margin-top: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
</style>

<body>
    <h1>Posting data to mongo</h1>
    <form class="containter" method="post" action="/">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control" name="title">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control" name="content">
        </div>
        <button>add mobgodb</button>
    </form>
    <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
    <form class="containter" method="post" action="/">
    <script>
        function myFunction() {
            var x = document.createElement("input");
            x.setAttribute("type", "text");
            x.setAttribute("name", "content2");
            x.setAttribute("class", "democlass");
            document.querySelector(".form-group").appendChild(x);
            const num = document.getElementById('input').value;
            console.log(num)
        }

    </script>
    </form>
    <script>src = "server.js"</script>
</body>

</html>
```

js file

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))

const url = //your mongodb's url;

mongoose.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
    .then((result) => console.log("Basarili"))
    .catch((err) => console.log(err))

const notesSchema = {
    title: String,
    content: String,
    content2: String
}

const Note = mongoose.model("Note", notesSchema);

app.get("/", function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
})

app.post("/", function(req, res) {
    let newNote = new Note({
        title: req.body.title,
        content: req.body.content,
        content2: req.body.content2
    });
    newNote.save();
    res.redirect('/');
})

app.listen(5500, function(){
    console.log("server is running on 5500");
})
```

if you have 2 text it works but i want add more text field and send all data to database

I create 2 text field and this datas send db

Comment: You want to store all the data which are posted from browser form?

Comment: yes i want store all data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to store all your request body you can use following code

```
app.post("/", function(req, res) {
    let newNote = new Note(req.body);
    newNote.save();
    res.redirect('/');
})
```

Comment: so how should my mongo schema be like this ?

Comment: Whatever you post will be stored and the your schema for the will be the your input field names

Answer (score 0):

[Incorrect word spelling in schema defination](https://i.stack.imgur.com/th8db.png)

Comment: oh i missed that , i fixed it ,it is working 3 text field but i want add  more text field how can i do schema and how can i do?

Comment: Use offical mongodb driver https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb, instead of mongoose if you want to write any fields to db.
Mongoose shema will filter out the fields not in it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).